# Hide app icon in iOS without Jailbreak?

Tags: ios, ios10

I am developing an Enterprise app that will not be uploaded to the store.

The application should not be visible to the users as per the enterprise request.
Is there a way to hide the application icon?

I have searched the web to find a solution but couldn't find any working one yet.

The most common one was the below but didn't work as well

```
  <key>SBAppTags</key>
  <array>
     <string>hidden</string>
  </array>
```

Any solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: there is no official API to customise the Springboard from an app, so probably you will need to find some hacky way to achieve that; however your app sounds like an app which is just about violating the privacy of the users. not cool.

Comment: @holex it is an enterprise app so no problem using private API.

Comment: then just use it.

Comment: @holex I guess that If I have already found a private API then no need to post a question here.